# Angular 2 loading animation freezes

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, loading

I've developed an Angular 2 app which has quite a bit of size and takes a moment to load (the `vendor.js` is about 5 MB big). To make the time a little more pleasant for the user I replaced the standard

```
<span class="loading">Loading...</span>
```

with a CSS animation (loading bar) or a GIF animation (I tried both) in the way:

```
<span class="loading"><img src="loading.gif" /><br/>Wait ...</span>
```

or

```
<span class="loading"><span class="circle-loader-with-css-animations"></span>Wait ...</span>
```

But none of this works since the animation (CSS or GIF) freezes during page load and when it continues the Angular app is ready and is displayed. So the result is a freezed loading animation and then the app = situation not better than before ...

BTW: Javascript (e.g. a `setInterval`) is also not executed during this load time. I tried to include the `vendor.js` with `async` and `defer` but without success.

Any ideas?

Edit: seems to be a Google Chrome issue - using Firefox the animation works smoothly.

Comment: Have the same problem in Firefox as well.

Comment: A late comment, but I'm just stumbling upon your question. Angular supports module lazy loading. 5 MB is way too much for an app, don't load it all at once. Load your home page, then lazy-load other modules as you go.

Comment: Can post your code here?

Comment: Are you using Service Worker to move loading to separate process?

Comment: @Xesenix Can you explain more how do you move loading script files and all other pre bootstrapped files to a service worker?

Comment: @TerranceJackson not sure where should I start are you aware of this https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro ? In general you want to run service worker as early as posible so it can takecontrol over loading of assets used by your page. But for some stuff like preloaders you may want to inline (base64) content of preloader inside base page html so its availebale just after first page content is downloaded by user. Also you want to heavily relay on lazy loading modules to load only necesary code to the point that you in your base content are loaders ect and anything more is loaded later.

Answer (score 1):

I use a loading spinner on my personal site using CSS; just thought I’d share my code because it works for me and doesn’t appear to have any issues with a large codebase. Obviously you’ll want to adjust it to your needs if this ends up working for you.

```css
@keyframes spin {
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid grey;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```